# UITableView behind NavigationBar after setting constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, constraints

I've added a TableView to my ViewController.

I have set the constraints like this:
[image]

[image]

Yet when i run the project the top of the firstcell(like 40px) is behind the NavigationBar:

[image]

What am i doing wrong here? Why is the TableView behind the navigationControllerBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not accounting for the navigation bar using the constraints. Set the top constraint to 50.

Since the scene in the Interface builder does not have a navigation bar - the constraints are not considering it and y (top) is set to 0 on the view, which does not have a navigation bar.

Either set the top constraint to 50 or put a bar in the view and set the top constraint to it.

Answer (score 5):

Do not just set the constraint to 50, that's wrong on so many levels.

Constrain table view's top to top layout guide of view controller. This is gonna handle rotations for you as well. In landscape the navigation bar might have smaller height, this accounts for it as well. If you set it to 50 it's probably gonna look ridiculous.

Or pin the table view to the top of the superview as you do and set the `contentInset` property to the height of bars (this is useful if you wanna have translucent navigation bar and see the cells under navigation bar while you scroll). You can do this in code or storyboard:

[image]